# Vlookup or Match multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am using Excel 2010. My set up is:

```
Column I: Election type X, U or S
Column J, Plan 1, 2, or 3
```

If I choose Election type U and Plan 2 I want to auto fill in column V, W, X and Y with predefined values. It would always be the same values if U and 2 are selected. I have been looking at Vlookup and it does not look like this would be the best option. I am thinking Index/Match might be better. I cannot find a firm formula example to be able to tell which formula would work best for my needs.

Does anyone know where I can get an example to possibly get this done?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a conditional in the those columns. Column A is Election type.

```
=IF(AND(A2="U",J2=2),"predefined value","")
```

Answer (score 0):

On a different sheet (which can be hidden later if preferred), setup your table like shown below.  The highlighted area should be named (I named it `tblResult`):

[image: tigeravtar lookup table setup]

Column C has a formula in cell C2 and copied down:

```
=A2&B2
```

The results in columns D:G are manually typed in.  They are the results for the combination of Election Type and Plan chosen based on your description earlier.  So now, in your main sheet, cell V2 and copied over to cell Y2 and then copied down (I'm assuming data starts on row 2 and that row 1 is a header row), use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($I2&$J2,tblResult,COLUMNS($V$1:V$1)+1,FALSE),"")
```

Or for an Excel 2003 and below friendly version:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($I2&$J2,tblResult,COLUMNS($V$1:V$1)+1,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP($I2&$J2,tblResult,COLUMNS($V$1:V$1)+1,FALSE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Index and Match you can make a formula like the one below and just create a lookup table like previously mentioned.  Use the `&` symbol to concatenate two different cells for the match.

[image]

If you want to get a more complex table, you can match separate columns in the look up table and enter your formula with `ctrl+shift+enter`

[image]